# ANR increased in Playstore Console - base.apk!libmonochrome.so

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

Recently my app getting more ANR and its shown playstore console and customer also saying i am getting the error like app not getting response.

Anyone faced this issue recently. I searched and reviewed the code. I am not getting any idea to reduce the count in ANR section in playstore.

Last 60 days: 60.3K
Impact Users : 7.37K
ANR Rate reached : 1.27 ( Bad Behaviour threshold Reached)

ANR captured details below.

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  #00  pc 0000000003bb31fc  /data/app/~~pJvDVIzVRXVRn3LFf0Xrkw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_447212034-4GGAI0wMqb7KjRqZCuXlgg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (???)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:195)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8004)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:631)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:978)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  #00  pc 00000000000803bc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #00  pc 000000000014c094  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #00  pc 0000000000388a0c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::NewLocalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+436)
  #00  pc 00000000031258a8  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_447212034-yXeNAnqAC86BvP9Y0cSclQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (???)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:336)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:182)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7822)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1026)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  #00  pc 000000000004b48c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #00  pc 00000000001af9e0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+164)
  #00  pc 000000000039ad1c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::NewLocalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+492)
  #00  pc 00000000031258a8  /data/app/~~pJvDVIzVRXVRn3LFf0Xrkw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_447212034-4GGAI0wMqb7KjRqZCuXlgg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (???)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:195)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8004)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:631)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

Comment: You are prolly using WebView ... maybe some version of it is FUp as it happend [many times before](https://www.engadget.com/android-gmail-stop-running-webview-234125352.html)

Comment: Thanks. So we have to raise the notification to members and ask to member and upgrade their webview version right?. that only way to reduce the ANR right?.